# -[CFString retain]: message sent to deallocated instance

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, cfstring

I am getting the error:

> "-[CFString retain]: message sent to deallocated instance"

when returning `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d is reserved for future use",reportID];` to `objectValueForTableColumn` in an `NSOutlineController`.

But when the literal `[@"This is a test" copy]` is used all is well.

I thought that `stringWithFormat` would return a pointer that would be retained by the receiver just like `[@"This is a test" copy]` does but I seem to be misunderstanding `stringWithFormat`.

Comment: You need to supply more context in order for people to help you without guessing. Edit the question and show the context of your `stringWithFormat` call. Explain why you are copying a literal string. Also indicate what sort of memory management you are using. With those details somebody may be able to help.

Comment: Using ARC. The method in questions returns an NSMutableArray of strings which are used to respond to NSOutlineViewDataSource protocol methods - 
- outlineView:child:ofItem: and objectValueForTableColumn. A few of the strings are created using stingWithFormat and it is those strings that are causing the "-[CFString retain]: message sent to deallocated instance" error. I changed the stingWithFormat construct with the literal copy as a debugging step but it is my understanding that [@"Test" copy] and [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d Test",10]; should both return freshly allocated NSStrings.

Comment: did you ever find out the solution for this?

Comment: I am sorry but it was so long ago I can't remember. I hope you are able to find an answer.